# Vectorized Portfolio Risk

Tags: python, numpy

Im have N pairs of portfolio weights stored in a numpy array and would like to calculate portfolio risk which is `w * E * w_T` where `w_T` is weight transpose. The way I came up with is to loop through each weight pair and apply the matrix multiplication. Is there a vectorized approach to this such that given a weight pair (or if possible N weights that all sum to 1) I apply a single covariance matrix to each row to get the risk (ie without loop)?

```
import numpy as np

w = np.array([[0.2,0.8],[0.5,0.5]])
covar = np.array([0.000046,0.000017,0.000017,0.000032]).reshape([2,2])


w1 = w[0].reshape([1,2]) # each row in w
#portfolio risk
np.dot(np.dot(w1,covar),w1.T)
```

Comment: Your code already demonstrates a vectorized approach. Please explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: `w1` is a single row in `w` so to get an array of portfolio risk, i will need to do that to each row which requires a loop. When I have a lot of rows, it will take a long time.

Comment: Is this meant to represent the existing, inner part of your loop? If so it would be useful if post a full example of your existing method (with the loop and some small input data in your current format) to work with.

Comment: no, so far in my analysis i don't need any loops. Its only this part that requires looping which I hope there is a faster way of doing it when my `w` is large

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Adam's answer is valid, but for big arrays, can result with very big temporary arrays (`NxN`), and unnecessary computations (computing the off-diagonal elements).

Here's a similar, yet much more efficient solution:
(I added another weight-pair, to distinguish between the different dimensions of the problem)

```
w = np.array([[0.2,0.8],[0.5,0.5], [0.33, 0.67]])
covar = np.array([0.000046,0.000017,0.000017,0.000032]).reshape([2,2])
(np.dot(w, covar) * w).sum(axis=-1)
=> array([  2.77600000e-05,   2.80000000e-05,   2.68916000e-05])
```

By using plain-multiplication in the second step, I'm avoiding the unnecessary compuations of the off-diagonals.

EDIT: explaining the temporary arrays

```
# first multiplication (in both solutions)
np.dot(w, covar).shape
(3, 2)
# second, my solution
(np.dot(w, covar) * w).shape
(3, 2)
# second, Adam's solution
np.dot(np.dot(w,covar),w.T).shape
(3, 3)
```

Now, if you have `N` sets of weights you want to compute risk for (in this example `N=3`), and `M` instruments in your portfolio (here `M=2`), and `N>>M`, you get an array which is much bigger with Adam's solution (`NxN`).  Not only that it will consume more memory, the computation populating the off-diagonal elements are expensive (matrix multiplication), and unnecessary.

Comment: ahhh even better, you guys are py-gods

Comment: can you explain a bit why there are temporary arrays in adams answer while your answer wont? I am new to python...thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your code is already set up for a vectorized approach, but you are only dealing with one row at a time. Grabbing the diagonals from the result when using your full weight matrix should give you what you want.

```
# portfolio risk
np.diagonal(np.dot(np.dot(w,covar),w.T))
```